# Discord py bot not triggering on_member_join function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My discord py bot wont trigger the "on_member_join" event. Everything else works fine. I have other event methods that trigger normally. What am i doing wrong here? It doesnt even print the console statement when people join.

```
# Libs
import discord # Version 1.2.5
from discord.ext import commands

# set discord API token
token = "MASKED"


# Initiate used objects
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") 

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} has joined the server.")
    for channel in member.server.channels:
        if str(channel) == "general":
            await bot.send_message(f"""Welcome to the server
                                   {member.mention}""")

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Discord is currently experiencing major IO latency and the API is very clumsy https://status.discordapp.com/

Comment: Even today the on_member_join event wont trigger.

Comment: Then I do not know the reason - at least the print should work (`member.server` and `bot.send_message` are not a thing anymore). Are your other prints displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If im right the problem is the user joined **before** your bot gets on.
Assuming you are using your alternate account to join your server for testing,
you should try printing a message after the bot gets on and then join the server.
You can do that by the following code.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready

```py
#prints 'logged on' when bot is ready
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged on')
```

So after logged on was printed you can then join the server and see if it works.

I hope this solves you problem!

Comment: Apologize, I have omitted the rest of the code. I do have an on_ready() event that lets me know when the bot has connected. The bot also responds to invoked commands using my prefix. However, even after testing again today, the on_member_join event still doesn't trigger.

Comment: Then im afraid i can't help you, sorry! It worked for me tho...

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game


Client=discord.client
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='^')
Clientdiscord=discord.Client()
client.remove_command("help")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'Recognised that a member called {member} joined')
    await member.send(".")
    print('Sent message to ' + member.name)
```

this is the script I use,I've added the topmost part of my bot to show where it goes.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as `discord.client`, or it is at least not what you think it is. The proper one is `discord.Client()`, but you don't need it because you've already instantiated `commands.Bot()` which inherits from `discord.Client` anyway. Whatever your `Client` variable is supposed to be, you don't even use it anyway, and the same with `Clientdiscord`. You've instantiated a client and proceed to not use it. So you should remove your variables `Client` and `Clientdiscord` as they are unused and unneeded.